# Cannot scale PhotoView with specific position in image resource

Tags: android, android-photoview, photoview

I have a photoView with fixed height and width below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChFnR.png)

The image demomap.jpg is used to load into photoView. By default, the image will be center of the imageview like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aITtG.png)

I follow the same approach [aslansari](https://github.com/Baseflow/PhotoView/issues/585#issuecomment-464050383) and a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48961771/how-to-scale-zoom-and-move-to-x-y-coordinates-of-bitmap-in-photoview).

The orgin size of the image is: 638x612. When running, the photoview bitmap will be auto expand to 1675x1607. So I add a scaleRate variable to map from real position to bitmap position. The problem is, the center of the photoview doesn't coincides with the position (442,300) in real image ( or () in bitmap). The correct position is offset from the photoview's center position by about 100 px in this case.

```
 val photoView = binding.photoView;
        photoView.scale = 1f
        photoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.demomap);

        val bitmap = photoView.drawable.toBitmap()

        val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
        options.inTargetDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT
        val bd = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            requireActivity().resources,
            R.drawable.demomap,
            options
        )
        val imageRealWidth = bd.width.toFloat()

        val scaleRate = bitmap.width / imageRealWidth;

        val demoBut = binding.button2

        Log.d("bitmap-size", "${bitmap.width.toFloat()}x${bitmap.height.toFloat()}") //1675.0x1607.0

        demoBut.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("scaleRate", scaleRate.toString()) //2.625392

            val x = 442f * scaleRate
            val y = 300f * scaleRate

            Log.d("focal x - y", "${x}-${y}") //1160.4232-787.6176

            val focalX: Float = x * photoView.right / bitmap.width
            val focalY: Float = y * photoView.bottom / bitmap.height

            val targetScale = 3f
            photoView.attacher.setScale(targetScale, focalX, focalY, false)
        }
```

I wonder how to fix this problem, or some thing wrong with this approach?